# I enabled display errors, but I still don't get an error

Tags: php, parsing

I am writing a little parser. No error is reported, even after adding the following lines at the top:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The `echo "..."` at the top doesn't produce any output either. Here is my code:

```
<?php

echo "this does not appear in the output";

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$toParse = '<<IF [2] > [3] FI>>';

$toParse = str_ireplace(" ", "", $toParse);
$toParse = str_ireplace("<<", "", $toParse);
$toParse = str_ireplace(">>", "", $toParse);

$toParse = str_ireplace("IF", "", $toParse, $if_1);
$toParse = str_ireplace("FI", "", $toParse, $if_2);

if($if_1 > 0 && $if_2 > 0) {
    $toParse = str_ireplace(">", "", $toParse, $gt);
    $toParse = str_ireplace("<", "", $toParse, $lt);
    $toParse = str_ireplace("==", "", $toParse, $eq);

    if($gt == 1 && $lt != 1 && $eq != 1) {
        $toParse = explode("][", $toParse);
        var_dump($toParse);
        if(count($toParse) > 2 || count($toParse) < 2) die ("Syntax Error!");
        for($i=0; i<count($toParse); i++) {
            $toParse[i] = str_ireplace("[", "", $toParse[i]);
            $toParse[i] = str_ireplace("]", "", $toParse[i]);
        }

        if($toParse[0] > $toParse[1])
            echo "1";
        else
            echo "0";
    }
    else if($gt != 1 && $lt == 1 && $eq != 1) {
        // not implemented
    }
    else if($gt != 1 && $lt != 1 && $eq == 1) {
        // not implemented
    }
    else
        die "syntax error";

} else if($if_1 > 0) die "syntax error";
else if($if_2 > 0) die "syntax error";

echo htmlspecialchars($toParse);

?>
```

What options do I have to configure to receive an error?

Comment: Do you have a server installed?

Comment: Do you get the output "hi" now or not?

Comment: Do you have modified your php.ini file or do you have a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get parse errors i would recommend this one.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to change the actual server configuration so that display_errors is on.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse flow order of following PHP statements and see.

From:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```